# xlsxwriter worksheet.write_blank apply to range

Tags: python, excel, format, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to write a format to a range of cells, using xlsxwriter.

```
worksheet.write_blank('A4:B4',None,cell_formatwhite)
```

this write_blank method seems to only apply to single cell references as it's formatting 'A4', but not 'B4'.  Is there a way I can apply this format to a range of cells without writing a value to the cells?  I want to change the color for all cells within a set excel range.

Comment: Couldn't you put that method in a loop to write over each cell in your desired range?

Comment: Thought about that as a solution but was hoping there was a cleaner way before writing that out

Comment: many possibilities, maybe use `worksheet.write_row()` something like `cell_format.set_font_color('white'); worksheet.write_row('A4:B4', ' '*2, cell_format)`? of course, adjust the format to the cell component you want to format.

Comment: This will work nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this function:

```
import string

# function to write blank format to range of cells
def range_write_blank(worksheet, col_start, col_end, row_start, row_end, cel_format):
    '''
    Writes blank to range of cells cel_format
    Takes:
    worksheet as Worksheet object
    col_start as uppercase letter string
    col_end as uppercase letter string
    row_start as int
    row_end as int
    cel_format as XlsXWriter Format object
    '''
    letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    for r in range(row_start, row_end):
        for c in range(letters.index(col_start), letters.index(col_end)+1):
            worksheet.write_blank(r, c, '', cel_format)

# usage example
some_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'blue'})

range_write_blank(worksheet, "A", "C", 0, 10, some_format)
```